# What is the best approach to run a 3 way ANOVA on large dataset with multiple dependent variables in R?

Tags: r, apply, anova

I have a dataset with 3 independent variables and several dependent variables (in real dataset over 150). I would like to run a 3 way ANOVA for every dependent variable and ideally shown only significant results. I know loops don't have the best reputation, but I am not really sure how to deal with this big dataset otherwise...
I know it is possiple to use FOR Argument or APPLY, but I am not sure how to use them with this dataset.

I added small examplarydataset:

```r
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39), Sex = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tratment1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), Treatment2 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), var1 = c(38, 
34, 97, 6, 99, 44, 4, 74, 12, 80, 61, 44, 100, 45, 31, 46, 4, 
92, 42, 52, 30, 55, 40, 31, 11, 7, 15, 67, 19, 14, 78, 19, 7, 
48, 39, 41, 29, 37, 10), var2 = c(38, 34, 47, 39, 83, 21, 66, 
87, 94, 55, 28, 52, 90, 96, 18, 36, 89, 77, 70, 49, 58, 16, 57, 
55, 50, 82, 88, 90, 54, 56, 27, 99, 50, 13, 94, 63, 84, 17, 71
), var3 = c(13, 11, 16, 38, 37, 36, 1, 26, 28, 61, 29, 12, 91, 
50, 34, 43, 100, 65, 14, 11, 23, 36, 31, 54, 72, 62, 31, 66, 
62, 73, 56, 31, 53, 23, 67, 86, 71, 96, 92), var4 = c(72, 78, 
32, 11, 1, 72, 95, 44, 23, 72, 67, 73, 100, 83, 2, 54, 67, 76, 
20, 79, 29, 75, 17, 96, 91, 35, 52, 71, 48, 15, 79, 6, 8, 57, 
78, 84, 87, 37, 31), var5 = c(22, 85, 60, 20, 53, 26, 65, 5, 
75, 20, 5, 47, 59, 13, 22, 90, 19, 51, 98, 93, 76, 17, 9, 5, 
57, 85, 21, 95, 40, 5, 30, 48, 83, 17, 90, 47, 72, 6, 36), var6 = c(34, 
9, 49, 7, 58, 55, 82, 65, 1, 36, 74, 48, 40, 26, 21, 37, 49, 
100, 36, 68, 78, 47, 77, 62, 38, 52, 36, 77, 46, 1, 99, 67, 40, 
43, 86, 17, 96, 33, 70), var7 = c(48, 94, 72, 13, 58, 4, 76, 
13, 45, 11, 41, 14, 36, 53, 2, 37, 1, 57, 23, 59, 7, 33, 48, 
52, 78, 64, 22, 63, 13, 56, 14, 28, 99, 74, 72, 39, 29, 49, 18
), var8 = c(98, 94, 53, 60, 72, 61, 62, 31, 28, 51, 94, 27, 8, 
46, 72, 91, 77, 2, 78, 45, 97, 39, 61, 12, 96, 59, 5, 60, 42, 
32, 42, 22, 50, 23, 32, 40, 18, 73, 52), var10 = c(90, 9, 51, 
88, 62, 36, 94, 96, 24, 21, 64, 82, 55, 33, 85, 98, 54, 68, 51, 
86, 22, 26, 60, 13, 29, 21, 4, 77, 64, 20, 28, 65, 97, 65, 61, 
20, 5, 74, 91)), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any idea is highly appreciated and welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with loops (for any problem that you can't easily vectorize): see chapter/circle 4 of https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf. All that something like `lapply()` does is to add a tiny bit of convenience by not requiring you to set up an empty list for the results.

I am more concerned with the statistical issues here (what do you hope to gain by fishing out the significant terms from a huge number of ANOVAs?), but that's more of a concern for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com): I'll [give you a (metaphorical) rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Give_someone_enough_rope) and let you decide what to do with it ...

Here's a start, if your data frame is `dd`:

```r
## vector of names of dependent (response) variables)
rvars <- colnames(dd)[-(1:4)]
## run an ANOVA on variable 'r'
fitfun <- function(r) {
    anova(lm(reformulate("Sex*Tratment1*Treatment2", response = r), data = dd))
}
## run ANOVAs on all vars, store results as a list
allfits <- lapply(rvars, fitfun)
names(allfits) <- rvars
## function to select significant values
reducefun <- function(a, alpha = 0.05) {
   subset(as.data.frame(a), `Pr(>F)` < alpha)
}
## select sig values for all fits
results <- lapply(allfits, reducefun)
## strip out empty data frames
results <- results[sapply(results, \(x) nrow(x)>0)]
```

Results:

```
$var1
    Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq  F value     Pr(>F)
Sex  1 3454.388 3454.388 4.312108 0.04622106

$var3
           Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq  F value      Pr(>F)
Sex         1 4422.754 4422.754 8.093038 0.007804113
Treatment2  1 2375.422 2375.422 4.346700 0.045408635
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much!
But is it possible to show only variables with significant results (in this example: var1, var3)?